# Python: Surface Integral over Mesh

Tags: python, integration, numeric, trimesh

## Question

How can I compute the surface integral of a specified function of the outer surface of a mesh in python?

## Code

I tried to create a minimal workable example. In this example, I try to compute the surface area of a box, which I define using [trimesh](https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh).

[image]

I only compute the surface area because it can be easily checked using the trimesh package (`mesh.area`), but in the future I will have much more complex functions, therefore, I *cannot use* the build-in [trimesh.integrate](https://trimsh.org/trimesh.integrate.html).

This is why I have turned to [quadpy](https://pypi.org/project/quadpy/) for the surface integration.

*Here is the code:*

```
import numpy as np
import quadpy
import trimesh


# CREATE THE BOX
# object (box)
box = trimesh.creation.box(extents=[0.3, 0.3, 0.3])

# show
box.show(viewer='gl')


# SURFACE INTEGRATION 

# 1 GET TRIANGLES of trimesh mesh object
triangles = box.triangles
# 2 SHAPE the triangles array into the shape accepted by quadpy
# trimesh -> (num_traingles, corners, xyz coordinates)
# quadpy ->  (corners, num_triangles, xyz_coords)
triangles_re = np.reshape(triangles,(
                       np.shape(triangles)[1],
                       np.shape(triangles)[0],
                       np.shape(triangles)[2])
                 )
# 3 DEFINE INTEGRATION FUNCTION 
def f(x):
    # -> get area of surface Integral[1, Area] = Area
    return np.ones(np.shape(x))

sol, error_estimate = quadpy.t2.integrate_adaptive(f, triangles_re,  1.0e-10)
```

## Issue

I am getting the following error:

> ```
> assert all(areas > minimum_triangle_area)
> ```
>
> AssertionError